# 2 same Strings , when compared in a Junit test it tells me they are not equal

Tags: java, junit, txt

I try to compare this .txt

```
USER bonb Bird
USER colc Colin Cook
EVENT alea Class ULE 11/11/2011 9:00 11/11/2011 13:00
EVENT alea Meeting MIC 11/11/2011 13:00 11/11/2011 14:00
EVENT alea Lunch Cafeteria 11/11/2011 14:00 11/11/2011 15:00
EVENT bonb Class ULE 11/11/2011 15:00 11/11/2011 19:00
EVENT bonb Meeting Library 11/11/2011 13:00 11/11/2011 14:00
```

In my class File.java I use this method to convert to String the content of the txt.

```
public String readElements() throws FileException {
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
        String lineAux = "";

        logger.info("Reads an element of the file: " + this.fileName);

        try {
            fr = new FileReader(this.fileName);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            lineAux = br.readLine();
            while (lineAux != null) {
                line.append(lineAux + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                lineAux = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn("File Error: Can´t open the file: " + this.fileName);
            throw new FileException("File Error: Can´t open the file " + this.fileName);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (null != fr) {
                    fr.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.warn("File error: Can´t open the file: " + this.fileName);
                throw new FileException("File error: Can´t open the file: " + this.fileName);
            }
        }
        return line.toString();
    }
```

I use this tests to try the File.Java
The TestReadElements compares that String with the content of the file. And when I use Junit in eclipse or the build.xml in a Linux terminal the test fails.

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.fileName = "./etc/test/rightCalendar.txt";
        this.file = new File(this.fileName);
    }

@Test
    public void testReadElements() throws FileException {
        assertEquals("USER alea Alex Archer\n" + "USER bonb Bonnie Bird\n" + "USER colc Colin Cook\n"
                + "EVENT alea Class ULE 11/11/2011 9:00 13:00\n" + "EVENT alea Meeting MIC 11/11/2011 13:00 14:00\n"
                + "EVENT alea Lunch Cafeteria 11/11/2011 14:00 15:00\n"
                + "EVENT bonb Class ULE 11/11/2011 15:00 19:00\n"
                + "EVENT bonb Meeting Library 11/11/2011 13:00 14:00\n", this.file.readElements());
    }
```

I don´t know where the problem is(if the problem is within the build.xml or some other file)
I have been changing little things for hours and I´m tired...
[These are the path files and the comparison that tells me it´s incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGo1r.png)

Comment: Is there a difference in the line endings? (`\r\n` vs `\n`?)

Comment: As an aside: don't call a class `File`: most people skimming your code would assume it's `java.io.File`, rather than your own class.

Comment: You might also want to consider using try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1):

You are explicitly concatenating the lines being read from the reader with `System.getProperty("line.separator")`; your screenshot suggests that you're running this on Windows (the path starts with `C:\Users`), which uses `\r\n` as the line separator.

Your expected string's lines use `\n` as the line separator.

Hence, the strings aren't equal because they use different line separators.

It would be better to keep things as a list of strings, and then just compare the lists (`List.equals` does pair-wise comparison of elements, so it's effectively the same - just without any confusion over line separators).

Comment: I have run it too in Linux and the result is the same